# Errors in First Bash File

Tags: linux, ksh

I am writing my first bash script and I keep getting errors and I am not real sure where I am going wrong. Below is the script I am trying to execute:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#Script Name: printnum.sh
# Verify the number of arguments and exit if not equal to 1`enter code here`
$mynum = "5"
echo $mynum
if [$mynum -gt 1]
then
    printf "error: program must be executed with 1 argument\n"
    printf "usage: $0 value (where value >= 1)\n"
    exit 1
fi
# Verify argument is a positive number
if [$mynum -lt 1]
then
    printf "error: argument must be a positive number\n"
    printf "usage: $0 value (where value >= 1)\n"
fi
# Store command line argument in variable i
$mynum="$i"
# Loop and print $i while decrementing variable to =1 (with comma)
while [$i -gt 1]
do
    printf "$i, "
done
```

and below is the errors I am getting:

```
./printnum.sh[3]: =: not found [No such file or directory]

./printnum.sh[5]: [: ']' missing
./printnum.sh[11]: [: ']' missing
./printnum.sh[16]: =: not found [No such file or directory]`enter code here`
./printnum.sh[17]: [: ']' missing
/export/home/hanko01/HOME/itec400/homework>
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are writing a `bash` script why do you have `#!/bin/ksh` as the shebang? `#!/bin/ksh` mean you are writing a `ksh` script. `ksh` is awesome BTW.

Comment: Also this line: `$mynum = "5"` should be written like this instead: `mynum="5"`.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the Shellcheck is definitely going to come in handy for me too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things first:

1. shebang should be #!/bin/bash if trying to use bash script. (Not required if already using bash, check by print $SHELL in terminal)
2. if (as well as while) condition should be properly spaced. For eg. if/space/[/space/condition/space/]
3. As told in comments don't use $ while assigning values.
4. $# for the number of command line arguments.

The rest you can understand from the corrected code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script Name: printnum.sh
# Verify the number of arguments and exit if not equal to 1 `enter code here`
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
        printf "error: program must be executed with 1 argument\n"
        printf "usage: $0 value (where value >= 1)\n"
        exit 1
fi
# Verify argument is a positive number
if [ $1 -lt 1 ]
then
        printf "error: argument must be a positive number\n"
        printf "usage: $0 value (where value >= 1)\n"
fi
# Store command line argument in variable i
i=$1
# Loop and print $i while decrementing variable to =1 (with comma)
while [ $i -gt 1 ]
do
        printf "$i, "
        i=$((i-1))
done
```

Comment: Thank you, i had to tweak it but this gave me the direction I needed to figure it out.